# spawn using in node js

Tags: python, node.js, spawn

``````js
    exports.marketOrder = async (req, res) => {   
        console.log("fgfdgf");   
        const { spawn } = require("child_process");   
        let action = "buy",     
            symbol = "XAUUSD",     
            lot = 0.1,     
            sl_points = 100,     
            tp_points = 100,
            deviation = 20;
        const process = spawn("python", [     "-c",     ``import metapython; print(metapython.open_trade("${action}", "${symbol}", ${lot}, ${sl_points}, ${tp_points}, ${deviation}) `````)`,   ]);   
        let order = null;   
        process.stdout.on("data", (data) => {     
            const frg = data.toString();     
            const regex = /order=(\d+)/;     
            const orderMatch = frg.match(regex);
            order = orderMatch ? parseInt(orderMatch[1]) : null;   
        }); 
    }; 
    router.post("/marketOrder", marketOrder);
``````

I tried calling the marketOrder API to trigger the marketOder function, but it didn't work, even though the module was running while the node was running.

Comment: "but it didn't work" means what?! Please take a moment and complete the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour, read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Explain your expected behavor and what error occours.

Comment: the api is not working for the above function?Is there any ideal Solutions?

Comment: "the api is not working". The same phrase just with other words as "but it didn't work". Name the things by its name. Read my posted links and explain things! Add details and use proper wording.

Comment: Sorry if this is unclear, but I'm trying to utilise a python function for orders in mt5 trading in node js using spawn, but it only works when running a js file with the node command. , I wanted order in MT5, when sending an API request however it did not work.

Comment: Your syntax seems to be incorrect, assuming your file looks exactly like the code you provided. You need to use `router.post("/marketOrder", exports.marketOrder)`, but Marc is correct about the question needing more detail.